# Trying to setup Laravel via Docker on Windows

Tags: windows, docker, laravel-8, php-8

I am following these instructions to Install Laravel:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/installation#getting-started-on-windows

I get this error when running on Terminal

```
curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
Docker is not running.
```

I am getting this error if I run on Git bash:

```
$ curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash
enterdocker: Error response from daemon: the working directory 'C:/Program Files/Git/opt' is invalid, it needs to be an absolute path.

See 'docker run --help'.
Please provide your password so we can make some final adjustments to your application's permissions.
bash: line 31: sudo: command not found code here
```

Comment: You need to provide bit more context for anybody to be able to help you. What is your setup and what you want to achieve...

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the problem was?

Comment: No, I think I just used another docker image

Answer (score 0):

So think the problem here is that it easy to miss the throw away comment in the docs : (emphasis mine)

> Next, you are ready to create your first Laravel project. Launch
> Windows Terminal and **begin a new terminal session for your WSL2 Linux**
> operating system

The command seems intended to be run from a WSL Linux distro, not a windows command line.

I had to install a wsl distro `wsl --install -d Ubuntu` (it will ask you to set up a linux user with password) after a while an ubuntu command prompt opened, I tried running

`curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

and got the message that `Docker is not running`

In my Docker desktop on my windows host, WSL distro support was not enabled, so I enabled that

[image: screenshot showing WSL integration in docker desktop]

I got the same error message after running the command again, existing a relaunching the linux command fixed that, I can log into it by just typing `ubuntu` in a windows cmd

The curl command now works - however after a false start I realised that WSL did not default me to the directory I wanted, so I needed to cd into it, my folder was in D:\Projects so in Ubuntu I ran

`cd /mnt/d/Projects`

then

`curl -s https://laravel.build/example-app | bash`

The install ran, asked for my linux user's password, then  I got the success message

> Thank you! We hope you build something incredible. Dive in with: cd
> example-app && ./vendor/bin/sail up

I ran the suggested commands, and it worked, default Laravel page accessible on http://localhost/

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna venture a guess that you're using Git Bash (or a similar console) under Window. Sail is just not happy at all to work under Git Bash:

1. The script from https://laravel.build/example-app will not escape paths in the docker command correctly,

```bash
docker run --rm \
    --pull=always \
    -v "$(pwd)":/opt \ 
    -w /opt \
    ...
```

When executed from within Git Bash the paths need to start with `//` e.g.

```bash
docker run --rm \
    --pull=always \
    -v "/$(pwd)":/opt \ 
    -w //opt \
    ...
```

*p.s.* the `sudo` commands will not work as Git Bash does not recognize `sudo`

2. Once you manage to create a new project the command `./vendor/bin/sail` will not work; you'll need to use `bash ./vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail` instead
3. Running `bash ./vendor/laravel/sail/bin/sail` will actually fail with

```
Unsupported operating system [MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045]. 
Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2).
```

Running the command `uname -s` in Git Bash returns `MINGW64_NT-10.0-19045` which is the `sail` script simply doesn't recognize (account for)

```bash
UNAMEOUT="$(uname -s)"

# Verify operating system is supported...
case "${UNAMEOUT}" in
    Linux*)             MACHINE=linux;;
    Darwin*)            MACHINE=mac;;
    *)                  MACHINE="UNKNOWN"
esac

if [ "$MACHINE" == "UNKNOWN" ]; then
    echo "Unsupported operating system [$(uname -s)]. Laravel Sail supports macOS, Linux, and Windows (WSL2)." >&2

    exit 1
fi
```

So, you either have to execute the sail command from within a `wsl2` console, or edit the script (either remove the check or add MINGW64 to the "support" machines)

```bash
case "${UNAMEOUT}" in
    MINGW64*)           MACHINE=linux;;
    Linux*)             MACHINE=linux;;
    Darwin*)            MACHINE=mac;;
    *)                  MACHINE="UNKNOWN"
esac
```

I have absolutely no idea why these issues have not been fixed (in years)